# How to check if the last TD of the last TR containre an empty select field and three empty inputs fields?

Tags: jquery

How to remove the last row if he is not the first row, otherwise, I check if the second select field and the three inputs of the last row are empty, if they are empty I delete the row, how to do it using jquery?

html :

```
 <table class="table" id="table2">
             <thead class=" text-primary"  >
                        <th>
                         Achats
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          Article
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          Prix Unitaire
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          Quantite
                        </th>
                           <th>
                          Delete
                        </th>
                      </thead>
                      </thead>
                    <tbody>
    <button id="done" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
    <tr >
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="446" id="id_form-0-id">
            <select name="form-0-Id_Achats" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Achats">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="63" selected>63</option>
</select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="form-0-Id_Article" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Article">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="1" selected>pc gamer</option>
  <option value="3">serveur ftp</option>
</select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" value="1.00" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" value="1" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Quantite">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-DELETE" id="id_form-0-DELETE">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

js :

i missing something in the code below

```
var $tbodyz = $("#table2 tbody")
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#done").on("click", function() {
    var $last = $tbodyz.find('tr:last');
    if ($last.is(':first-child')) {
      console.log('not last');
    } else {
      var inputs = $last.find("select");
      var inputd = $last.find("input:empty");
      if (inputs.length == 1 && inputs.val() = "" && inputd.length == 2 {
         last.remove()  
      } else {
        console.log("Not empty");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to remove the last row and if there are inputs and select empty in that row. Just click `update` to delete the last `row` as you wanted.

I have used `filter` function to go through all the last row input to make all are empty before removing the row on clicking `update`

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/21o6rvms/

Run Snippet to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#done").on("click", function() {
    var last = $("#table2 tbody").find('tr:last');
    if (last.is(':first-child')) {
      console.log('Not Last Row');
    } else {
      var emptySelects = last.find("select");
      var emptyInputs = last.find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
      });
      if (!emptySelects.val() && emptyInputs.length != 0) {
        last.remove()
      } else {
        console.log("Inputs OR select not empty");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table2">
  <thead class=" text-primary">
    <th>
      Achats
    </th>
    <th>
      Article
    </th>
    <th>
      Prix Unitaire
    </th>
    <th>
      Quantite
    </th>
    <th>
      Delete
    </th>
  </thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <button id="done" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="446" id="id_form-0-id">
        <select name="form-0-Id_Achats" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Achats">
          <option value="">---------</option>
          <option value="63" selected>63</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="form-0-Id_Article" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Article">
          <option value="">---------</option>
          <option value="1" selected>pc gamer</option>
          <option value="3">serveur ftp</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" value="1.00" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" value="1" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Quantite">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-DELETE" id="id_form-0-DELETE">
      </td>
    </tr>









    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="446" id="id_form-0-id">
        <select name="form-0-Id_Achats" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Achats">
          <option value="">---------</option>
          <option value="63" selected>63</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="form-0-Id_Article" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Article">
          <option value="">---------</option>
          <option value="1" selected>pc gamer</option>
          <option value="3">serveur ftp</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" value="1.00" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" value="1" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Quantite">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-DELETE" id="id_form-0-DELETE">
      </td>
    </tr>







    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="446" id="id_form-0-id">
        <select name="form-0-Id_Achats" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Achats">
          <option value="" selected>---------</option>
          <option value="63">63</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="form-0-Id_Article" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Id_Article">
          <option value="" selected>---------</option>
          <option value="1">pc gamer</option>
          <option value="3">serveur ftp</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-Quantite">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form-0-DELETE" id="id_form-0-DELETE">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

my own solution

```
var $tbodyz = $("#table2 tbody")

console.log('now');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#done").on("click", function() {
    var last = $("#table2 tbody").find('tr:last');
    if (last.is(':first-child')) {
      console.log('Not Last Row');
    } else {
      var inputs = last.find("select");
      var inputd= last.find("input");
      var inputf= last.find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first');
      var inputl= last.find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:last');

      if (inputs.length == 2 && inputs.last().val() =='' && inputf.val() =='' && inputl.val() == '') {
        last.remove()
      } else {
        console.log("Inputs OR select not empty");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice effort. But this way you will have more lines of code and repetition as well.. Its ideal to have less code but same results. :)